# Filter items which array contains any of given values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a set of documents like

```
{
    tags:['a','b','c']
    // ... a bunch properties
}
```

As stated in the title: Is there a way to filter all documents containing any of given tags using Nest ?

For instance, the record above would match ['c','d']

Or should I build multiple "OR"s manually ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*Edit: The bitset stuff below is maybe an interesting read, but the answer itself is a bit dated. Some of this functionality is changing around in 2.x. Also Slawek points out in another answer that the `terms` query is an easy way to DRY up the search in this case. Refactored at the end for current best practices. —nz*

You'll probably want a [Bool Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) (or more likely [Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) alongside another query), with a `should` clause.

The bool query has three main properties: `must`, `should`, and `must_not`. Each of these accepts another query, or array of queries. The clause names are fairly self-explanatory; in your case, the `should` clause may specify a list filters, a match against any one of which will return the document you're looking for.

From the docs:

> In a boolean query with no `must` clauses, one or more `should` clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to match can be set using the `minimum_should_match` parameter.

Here's an example of what that Bool query might look like in isolation:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      { "term": { "tag": "c" }},
      { "term": { "tag": "d" }}
    ]
  }
}
```

And here's another example of that Bool query as a filter within a more general-purpose [Filtered Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "title": "hello world" }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          { "term": { "tag": "c" }},
          { "term": { "tag": "d" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Whether you use Bool as a query (e.g., to influence the score of matches), or as a filter (e.g., to reduce the hits that are then being scored or post-filtered) is subjective, depending on your requirements.

It is generally preferable to use Bool in favor of an [Or Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html), unless you have a reason to use And/Or/Not (such reasons do exist). The Elasticsearch blog has more information about the different implementations of each, and good examples of when you might prefer Bool over And/Or/Not, and vice-versa.

Elasticsearch blog: [All About Elasticsearch Filter Bitsets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/)

*Update with a refactored query...*

Now, with all of *that* out of the way, the `terms` query is a DRYer version of all of the above. It does the right thing with respect to the type of query under the hood, it behaves the same as the `bool` + `should` using the `minimum_should_match` options, and overall is a bit more terse.

Here's that last query refactored a bit:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "title": "hello world" }
    },
    "filter": {
      "terms": {
        "tag": [ "c", "d" ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: minimum_should_match is now deprecated

Comment: minimum_should_match will not solve the problem, if you also filter by another array, where you need the normal "or" behaviour.

Answer (score 84):

**elasticsearch 2.0.1:**

There's also [terms query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) which should save you some work. Here example from docs:

```
{
  "terms" : {
      "tags" : [ "blue", "pill" ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
  }
}
```

Under hood it constructs boolean should. So it's basically the same thing as above but shorter.

There's also a corresponding [terms filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html).

So to summarize your query could look like this:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "title": "hello world" }
    },
    "filter": {
      "terms": {
        "tags": ["c", "d"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With greater number of tags this could make quite a difference in length.

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work.  Would you mind checking it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252789/elastic-search-rails-combine-multi-match-and-filter

Comment: `minimum_should_match` is deprecated and will fail.

Comment: @AinTohvri actually in elasticsearch 2.0.1 minimum_should_match still working and official doc does not mark it as deprecated.

Comment: how to work if i dont want specific keyword in tags.. lets say i have 5 keywords a,b,c,d,e.. i dont want c keyword in tags. what will be the query?

Comment: Kinda depends on what version of elasticsearch you are on. But in most cases you just need to negate condition. For example, if you use exactly the same `terms` condition in `mustNot` clause of `boolean` query it will search all the documents which don't have any of the tags.

Comment: @AinTohvri why minimum_should_match is deprecated?

Comment: `minimum_should_match` is only part of `terms_set` query now

Comment: How to use regex with this query?

Answer (score 24):

Whilst this an old question, I ran into this problem myself recently and some of the answers here are now deprecated (as the comments point out). So for the benefit of others who may have stumbled here:

A `term` query can be used to find the exact term specified in the reverse index:

```
{
  "query": {
   "term" : { "tags" : "a" }
}
```

From the documenation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Alternatively you can use a `terms` query, which will match all documents with any of the items specified in the given array:

```
{
  "query": {
   "terms" : { "tags" : ["a", "c"]}
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

One gotcha to be aware of (which caught me out) - how you define the document also makes a difference. If the field you're searching in has been indexed as a `text` type then Elasticsearch will perform a full text search (i.e using an `analyzed` string).

If you've indexed the field as a `keyword` then a keyword search using a 'non-analyzed' string is performed. This can have a massive practical impact as Analyzed strings are pre-processed (lowercased, punctuation dropped etc.) See (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/term-vs-full-text.html)

> To avoid these issues, the string field has split into two new types: text, which should be used for full-text search, and keyword, which should be used for keyword search. (https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Answer (score 9):

For those looking at this in 2020, you may notice that accepted answer is deprecated in 2020, but there is a similar approach available using `terms_set` and `minimum_should_match_script` combination.

Please see the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964675/3223450) in the SO thread

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "tags" : ["c", "d"]
        }
    }
}
```