# Query for Documents and Filter on specific value in nested List of Strings (i.e. Tags)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a bit of a problem with NEST and its query & filter syntax regarding a relatively simple document structure.

Given a Document type 'BlogPosts' which looks like this:

```
public class BlogPosts
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> ReferencedUserIds { get; set; }
}
```

I can send over instances to my ES instance and have them indexed just fine, i.e. the sent / indexed json looks like this:

```
 {
  "id": "ad61de92-c6f6-49c1-84eb-0a4dfdf86cc0",
  "userId": "c43e1be7-0b8c-4271-bf29-7434719fbcbf",
  "createdAt": "2015-04-05T11:23:58.1017261Z",
  "content": "Some Specific Word in here",
  "tags": [
    "Some",
    "Tag",
    "SomeSpecialTag"
  ],
  "referencedUserIds": [
    "f6a714a0-318d-49d7-9940-f0480c002577",
    "e582c24c-1c82-43f8-8e80-09e19749a0a3",
    "11165e0b-8e4f-466a-8c37-e0cfec81850c"
  ]
}
```

Now using NEST I can easily query for all BlogPosts with that 'SomeSpecialTag' tag like this:

```
var postsQueriedForSpecialTag = elasticClient.Search<BlogPosts>(postSearch => postSearch
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(
                    queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor.Match(match => match.OnField(posts => posts.Tags).Query("SpecialTag"))));
```

.. but what I'd really want is

**a) *Query*** for specific content and

**b) *Filter*** down based on specific Tags (and optionally also on a specific UserId)

but i.e. this returns 0 documents:

```
var postsFilteredForSpecialTag = elasticClient.Search<BlogPosts>(postSearch => postSearch
    .Index(indexName)
    .Query(
        queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor.QueryString(q => q.Query("Some Specific Word")))
        .Filter(descriptor => descriptor.Nested(filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor.Path(posts => posts.Tags).Filter(descriptor1 => descriptor1.Term(posts => posts.Tags, "SpecialTag")))));
```

.. and I wonder why. Or more precisely, what would be the correct NEST syntax to  filter on nested `List<string or Guid>` structures as mentioned above?

***Update:**

Following Jettro's hint(s) and using a 'Should' filter instead (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28001971/2591) it does work perfectly now. The final query + filter code now looks like this:

```
var postsFilteredForSpecialTag = elasticClient.Search<BlogPosts>(postSearch => postSearch
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(
                    queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor.QueryString(q => q.Query("Some Specific Word")))
                    .Filter(descriptor => descriptor.Bool(filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor.Should(descriptor1 => descriptor1.Term(posts => posts.Tags, "specialtag")))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem in your mapping. Although I am not a NEST expert, it could be a general problem. It can be that the default Filter is a Term filter? When the mapping for the tags field is not specified it is the standard analyser. With that analyser, Capital characters are removed. Doing a query will have the same effect, but a term filter will not be analyzed and therefore the term with the Capitals "SpecialTag" will not be found. Change it to "special tag" and try again or make the field not_analyzed in your mapping.

Comment: thanks for the push in the right direction. I added 'not_analyzed' to the Tags property and moreover switched the filter statement to a should + term filter (based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/28001971/2591). and now it works as expected / desired!