# Matching multiple values in same field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have "routes" field as long type (Im storing array of values in that Example  `1. [5463, 3452] , 2. [5467, 3452]`) in mapping. In the following query i 
want to retrieve data which matches both 5463, 3452 in same record

```
GET /flight_routes/_search
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
    "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "routes": [5463, 3452]
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

But it is returning document which matches with either one value. Should I have to migrate the mapping type to nested to handle this or 
any other way to get it through query itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter items which array contains any of given values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001632/filter-items-which-array-contains-any-of-given-values)

Comment: I know boolean - must filter along with multiple "term" i can achieve this. Would like to know is there any handy way get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`terms_set` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) with a `minimum_should_match_script` that returns the length of the array

```
POST /flight_routes/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms_set": {
            "routes" : {
                "terms" : [5463, 3452],
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                   "source": "params.nb_terms",
                   "params": {
                      "nb_terms": 2
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will apply "OR" Condition., I want to retrieve routes which has both 5463 and 3452.

Comment: Have you tried it? `minimum_should_match_script` will return 2 in this case and hence 2 terms must match

Comment: Yes I tried., it returns documents which has both 5463, 3452 and 5463 alone. I need only documents which has 5463, 3452 (exact match)

Comment: My bad, I've updated the script, actually you need to pass the number of terms in the query and that will work.